# Principal ideals and UFD's

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Problems 1-6 form a project designed to prove that if R is a UFD and every nonzero prime ideal of R is maixmal, then R is a PID.

Let I be an ideal of R, since {0} is principal, we can assume that $I \not= \{0\}$. Since R is a UFD, every nonzero element of I can be written as $up_1...p_t$ where u is a unit and the $p_i$ are irreducible, hence prime. Let r=r(I) be the minimum such t. We are going to prove by induction on r and I is principal.

1) If r=0, show that $I = \langle 1 \rangle = R$.

**Answer**

If r=0 then I contains a unit, so that $1 \in I$ and I=R.

I'm not sure if I get this, because I'm having trouble understanding the notation r=r(I). What is that? Does it mean that we multiply r by I? If so, then r=0 just gives us 0=0. So I'm sure that I'm misunderstading that notation...

Thank you in advance

Comment: r is a positive integer that depends on I - so, if you change I, then r might change too. Alternatively, r is a function from ideals to positive integers, hence the notation r(I). It doesn't mean anything like multiplication - it's just a reminder that r changes with I.

Comment: This problem seems incomplete, since you basically launch into a proof without first stating what you are trying to prove. (At first reading, it seemed to me you or your source are trying to prove that all UFDs are PIDs, which is not true.)

Comment: This is not my proof, it's basically the first part of the proof from the exercises. I will edit my question so it's clearer.

Comment: Yeah, the alternate condition - that every prime ideal is also maximal -  was really needed to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $\,r\,$ denotes the length of the shortest element in $\,I,\,$ i.e. the element having the least number of prime factors. If $\,r = 0\,$ then a nonzero element of $\,I\,$ has no prime factors, so it is a unit.

The proof employs following pretty generalization of the Euclidean algorithm to arbitrary PIDs. The *Dedekind-Hasse criterion* states that
a domain $\rm\:D\:$ is a PID iff given any $\rm\:0\ne b,c \in D,\:$
either $\rm\:b\:|\:c\:$ or there exists a $\rm D$-linear combination of $\rm\:b,c\:$ that's "smaller" than $\rm b,\:$ where size is measured by naturals  (or any ordinal), so that induction (or descent) works.

It is clear that such a domain must be a PID, since 
the smallest element in an ideal must divide all others.
Conversely, since a PID is UFD, an adequate metric is
the number of prime factors (since if  $\rm\:b\nmid c\:$ then their gcd $\rm\:d\:$
must have fewer prime factors; for if $\rm\:(b,c) = (d)\:$ then
 $\rm\:d\:|\:b\:$ *properly,* else $\rm\:b\:|\:d\:|\:c\:$ contra hypothesis). Notice Euclidean descent by the Division Algorithm is just a
special case, hence Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ PID ($\Rightarrow$ {UFD, Bezout} $\Rightarrow$ GCD).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm still not sure if I get that notation. I understand that r denotes the length of the shortest element in I. I also understand that if r=0, then $I= \langle I \rangle$. But I don't understand the notation r=r(I). Why do they say that r **equals** r(I)? Isn't r(I) the notation for saying that we are multiplying r by (I)?

Comment: No, $\ r(I)\ $ denotes the function $\,r\,$ evaluated at $\,I.\, $ Here $\ r = r(I)\ $ means that, since $\,I\,$ is fixed, we are are abbreviating $\,r(I)\,$ to $\,r\,$ in what follows. If that's confusing you can replace $\,r\,$ by $\,r(I).\ $